# Further elaborate of main() method in Android

Tags: java, android, frameworks, program-entry-point

I konw that many people have asked the question of no main() in Android.
However, no one made the final conclusion.

In browser applets, there is no main().
In Android oncreate(), there is no main().
It is because there is a framework in the middle.

Can I say Android is no main(), but the Android framework will handle the main() somewhere we don't need to concern, since
Android is written from Java. There must hava a main() at last.

Is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Android source code not have a main method and still run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221467/how-can-android-source-code-not-have-a-main-method-and-still-run)

Comment: Have you read my question carefully? I have read all the past questions, but no one exactly conclude my question. That's why I ask my question.

Comment: Did you carefully read the linked question? Android applications don't need a main method because the manifest file specifies the entry point. Your statement "There must have a main() at last" is false.

Comment: I find a good explaination in this site (You may translate to English):http://www.hkprogram.com/index1/section8.html